# UIActivityViewController No Activities, Hide Lower Bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using `UIActivityViewController` but I am not using any `UIActivity` subclasses, just the default system ones.

Is it possible to hide the lower half of the `UIActivityViewController` seen as it is not used?

Currently, I have the share options in the top half, then the decider line and the bottom half just has a 'More' button that gives no options.

Comment: File a bug report with Apple. `UIActivityViewController` shouldn't show the unused portion.